# Activiti Process Configuration points to H2 always

Tags: java, activiti

I am trying to read Process Engine from activiti.cfg.xml where I have configured DB2 and set up datasource. But during debugging I can see that the Process configuration is still of H2. Also while trying to create Process Instance fromr run Time Service , it turns up as null. Below is the code

```
ProcessEngineConfiguration.createProcessEngineConfigurationFromResource("activiti.cfg.xml", "processEngineConfiguration")


<bean id="processEngineConfiguration" class="org.activiti.spring.SpringProcessEngineConfiguration">
    <property name="databaseType" value="db2" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="customDataSource" />
 </bean>
 <bean id="dataSourceTarget" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName" value="XXX"></property>
```

```
<bean id="customDataSource" class="XXX">
    <property name="targetDataSource"><ref local="dataSourceTarget"/></property>
    <property name="schemaName"><value>XXX</value></property>
</bean>


            RuntimeService runtimeService = processEngine.getRuntimeService();
        processInstance = runtimeService.startProcessInstanceByKey(processDefinitionName, processVariablesMap);
```

How to change the configuration to DB2 and also get Process Instance?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing the call of `buildProcessEngine()`

```
ProcessEngineConfiguration.createProcessEngineConfigurationFromResource("activiti.cfg.xml", "processEngineConfiguration").buildProcessEngine()
```

instead of

```
ProcessEngineConfiguration.createProcessEngineConfigurationFromResource("activiti.cfg.xml", "processEngineConfiguration")
```

Comment: I have the built the process engine too.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the database properties in activiti.properties file comment the H2 configuration and specify your own DB configuration. And this is for activiti enterprise... From your code it seems you are using the community one then try to create standalone process engine instead of using .xml file...

Comment: I have already done that                                                                 <bean id="processEngineConfiguration" class="org.activiti.spring.SpringProcessEngineConfiguration">
    <property name="databaseType" value="db2" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="customDataSource" />
 </bean>

Comment: I am talking about the the activiti.properties file which is available at following path: activiti\tomcat\webapps\activiti-app\WEB-INF\classes\META-INF\activiti-app

Comment: Are you using Activiti enterprise or community? the path specified above is for enterprise...

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to create a runtime in a class that extends JavaDelegate, it's simplier than that. You need your new process to inherit your previous runtime properties.

So instead of doing

```
   RuntimeService runtimeService = processEngine.getRuntimeService();
```

you can get your actual execution runtime:

```
public class CreateNewInstance implements JavaDelegate {

    private String processKey;
    private Map<String, Object> variables;

    public void execute(DelegateExecution execution) throws Exception {

        // Load all the variables into the Map
        variables = execution.getVariables();

        RuntimeService runtimeService = execution.getEngineServices()
                .getRuntimeService();
        runtimeService.startProcessInstanceByKey(processKey, variables);

    }
}
```

Hope that helps.